# How can I change the order of the packages in the output of Auriga Doclet?

Tags: javadoc, doclet

I am creating my JavaDoc documentation as PDF using [Auriga Doclet 1.0.](http://aurigadoclet.sourceforge.net/)

But that generated PDF contains the packages orderes like this: Service, Response, VO, based on alphabetical order.

But I need them ordered like this: Response, Service, VO.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Actually, your "contains" example is not alphabetical, while your "need" one is alphabetical. Did you mix the examples?

Answer (score 0):

AurigaDoclet uses the Java Doclet API to extract the information and generate pdf from the same. The Doclet API generates the package in that order and AurigaDoclet just displays in the same order. I am not sure if its possible to define a custom order for package display.